# Entity Framework error - Schema specified is not valid

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, umbraco

I am trying to use Entity Framework to get access to Umbraco DB.

On my localhost it works fine. But for some reason, when I run it on IIS server, I get this error:

> Schema specified is not valid.
>   Errors:
>   The relationship 'Mast_WebAdminModel.FK_cmsContent_umbracoNode_id' was not loaded because the type 'Mast_WebAdminModel.umbracoNode' is not available.
>   The following information may be useful in resolving the previous error:
>   The required property 'umbracoUser2NodePermission' does not exist on the type 'DAL.Umbraco.umbracoNode'......

I have no idea why.

Please help me!

Comment: Can I ask you why are you trying to access the Umbraco DB directly and not via Umbraco Services instead?

Comment: yes, i am using angular 5 app.

Comment: You can make a Umbraco.Web.WebApi.UmbracoApiController to return the data to your app and use the umbraco Services https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/management/services/ inside of it